# Running batch file, call another batch, ctrl+c out of that, then return to the first?

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script which mount's a .vhd file and creates a junction point, the it call's another batch script which runs some things on the mounted vhd/junction point. When that script finishes, it then comes back to the 1st batch script and deletes junction point, unmounts .vhd then exits.

The problem is the second script needs to exit properly in order to run the rest of the first script, when most of the users will just ctrl+c and close the second script.

Is it possible to prevent this from happening, either by not allowing the ctrl+c cancel or somehow restart the first batch file after the call has happened?

Comment: A bit of 4x2 applied to the head and shoulders of your users would fix that.  There is a `break` command but it doesn't prevent users stopping a batch file, and it may be outdated anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Endoro's answer, even though it didn't work for me, it made me remember start, i always forget start and just use call. anyway the solution i found was was to do this:

```
2>nul (
echo N|start /wait "" cmd /c C:\2nd-batch.BAT
)
```

it creates a new window for the 2nd-batch.bat which allows the dumbuser to even exit it via the X button and it still completes the rest of the 1st-batch.bat

Answer (score 1):

try this to start the 2nd batch file:

```
start /b /w "" 2nd-batch.bat
```

Comment: @foxidrive  Thank you. Let's see, if it can help :)

Comment: thanks it didn't work, as i didn't realise before the 2nd batch file(i didn't write that one) does some rather convoluted stuff with other programs, so when it was terminated it just dropped you back to c:\