# How to terminate only the inner batch job

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting, terminate, control-c

Let's say there is some .bat file that is required to run inside .cmd batch script. This inner .bat file has a series of user interactions on a local host, and are only able to be ended using ctrl+c.

**The question is:** Is there some way to make the outer batch script resume after the inner script is terminated? Or is the ctrl+c the end all be all?

I've tried giving the inner script a different way out only to be told I'm not allowed to change that file. I've also done a fair amount of research and haven't found a solution. Forgive me if I've overlooked something! I'd like to avoid having two windows or extraneous termination messages pop up.

Comment: So you are using `call inner.bat` to run the inner script? Perhaps `cmd /C inner.bat` or `start "" /WAIT inner.bat` could help...

Comment: @aschipfl thanks that's quite helpful, the cmd /C works but now I get two Termination requests. Would like to just terminate the inner one and have the outer one continue smoothly

Comment: @aschipfl same issue with the start in new window. Thanks though, definitely closer.

Comment: @aschipfl other good option would be to have two termination messages where the first one is the standard message but the second one is suppressed/custom message. Any advice on this?

Comment: What about combining like `start "" /WAIT cmd /C inner.bat` or `cmd /C start "" /WAIT inner.bat`? concerning a custom message I am afraid I cannot help you...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running batch file, call another batch, ctrl+c out of that, then return to the first?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18181887/running-batch-file-call-another-batch-ctrlc-out-of-that-then-return-to-the-f)

Comment: You might also be interested in this post: [batch script if user press Ctrl+C do a command before exitting](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27131024)

Comment: @aschipfl Thanks, between those two I'll be all set. Feel free to post those two as an answer if you want! Sorry I missed them in my previous searches. Second link is the most helpful, not sure I like the double window idea. Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116617/discussion-between-alex-rosenfeld-and-aschipfl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of to handle this is to use the following line in `outer.cmd` to call `inner.bat` -- with the disadvantage of receiving a new command prompt window for the execution of `inner.bat`:

```
start "" /WAIT cmd /C "inner.bat"
```

(Exchanging `start` and `cmd` does not work as the new window might unintentionally remain open.)

Note that for `inner.bat`, all the console input and output are handled via the new window, hence any redirections for `outer.cmd` (e. g., `outer.cmd > "return.txt"`) will not include data from `inner.bat`.